# Using curses library to create GUI for different operating systems

Tags: operating-system, curses

It would appear that the curses library is specific to the operating system. Given this, I would like to know:

1. Can the curses library be used in a non-standard operating system
   (as in not Windows, Linux, Mac OS, so on...)?; and,
2. If the curses library is not limited to those operating systems, would I have to write my own implementation of the functions
   described in the library or could I simply call the functions in a
   similar fashion as in:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   ...
   printf("%s", "something");
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, you can use curses in any Unix-like operating system, that includes Linux and MacOSX.  Both of them provides curses.  For the other operating system, you can check [PDCurses](http://www.projectpluto.com/win32a.htm).  That said, you can make your code portable.  However, I would not consider it for iOS, Android, etc (although still possible to do it).

For your second question, once you use curses you have to stick with that.  You can not use the standard I/O.  Curses provides its own directives to print out.  Instead of `printf`, you would use `printw`.  Check the ["Hello world" example](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/helloworld.html) from the [curses tutorial](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) to get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

The cures library primarily operates as an abstraction between the terminal capabilities and the application.  I would say yes, you can theoretically implement anything

Your code snippet makes no sense in the context of the question.... where is the use of curses?

Your question is also unclear regarding the OS you want to use.

If you are looking for a shortcut you can probably use terminal escape codes directly

Comment: I was vague as to the Operating system I wished to use because I asked this question with the idea of building a small operating system. I would like to know how to build a moderately useful UI at some point. The example I choose for the code is not the best, but I have not had any experience with curses before and hoped I could receive some direction on the subject.